Gold tag badges don't apply to synonymized tags
(I want to preemptively say that I do not contribute to Stack Overflow for the reputation or the badges)
On Stack Overflow, I possess the selenium Gold badge, but the permissions don't seem to apply to its synonyms. Does this selenium badge also apply to its synonym selenium-webdriver? Or do I need to unlock a badge for that tag?
I had just attempted to close a selenium-webdriver question, but the Gold badge permissions were ignored.
Personally, I think this may be a bug, thus I'm tagging as such. I think if a member unlocked a Gold badge for a tag, if later that tag gets added as a synonym, I think that the permissions should transfer to that one.

At least from the mod perspective, I don't think we differentiate much between tags that are merged and tags that are merely synonymized (other than that the latter is far easier to undo, but has more bugs), so I'm inclined to say that this sounds like a bug.

The system considers them separate tags, so much so that search won't surface questions that only have the child tag. So from a system perspective I don't think that it's a bug. Even if the designed behaviour is not good and would be better if the system treated them as if they were the same tag for all intents and purposes. To be clear though I 100% support this as a feature that should be added.

@HenryEcker I don't think that behavior is necessarily designed...at least the fact that search affirmatively replaces synonyms, but the backend only checks against the unreplaced tag, is certainly a bug.

@RyanM I agree the fact that search doesn't work is a bug—not being able to use the search feature to find questions that you're looking for is a bug with search. However, its cause is that synonyms are treated as distinct tags. Searching for [a] only surfaces [a] because [a] <> [b] even if search will rewrite [b] -> [a]. My point is that I don't believe a gold-tag badge not applying to a child synonym is a bug because it is consistent with how synonyms are treated everywhere. [a] <> [b] so you can't use a tag badge for [a] to close a question with [b].

Again though, I think it would be better if [a] and [b] were treated as the same tag for everything including search and tag privileges. I'd even like to see them have a combined tag score so that both tags contributed to earning tag badges. But I don't have any indication that there is any connection between synonyms at a system level other than tag edit and search text rewriting. For that reason, I feel like this would be a request for new functionality since this is not the behaviour demonstrated by the system anywhere else.

I agree, this is a bug for all intents and purposes. It likely would work the other way around; if [tag:selenium] were the parent/target of the synonym, you would be able to close [tag:selenium-webdriver] questions. This ought to be mod-tagged [meta-tag:status-review]

Wait, does this imply that synonymizing python-3.x to python wouldn't enable me to dupehammer those questions with my python gold tag badge? :(

@KarlKnechtel you just need to work harder so your python-3.x badge becomes gold too. And then Python 4 comes around and the circus starts all over again.

I wonder what Zoe did https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1837609 except approving that synonym. Somehow the OP also "lost"  263 (394 - 131) answers because I assumed that when [selenium] - >  [selenium-webdriver]  those 394 answers would go into the selenium-webdriver tag. Did a burninate take place that we're not aware of?

A workaround would be to edit the question you want to close, then the synonymized tag will be replaced with the target tag. Thus you'd now be able to dupe hammer the question. Nasty, but it works...

@rene For the record, that appears to be a consequence of the previously-linked search bug

This is one of the posts mentioned in the recent announcement: We spent a sprint addressing your requests — here’s how it went

Thank you for reporting, we have fixed this issue.

Should this be marked as (status-completed), too: Mjolnir doesn't work on old synonyms (should it?) There are also some posts on [meta.se]: Which questions count for the purpose of tag badges and dupehammer for the tag synonyms? and Gold-badge duplicate hammers don't appear to check tag synonyms as far as I can tell; is this so, and should it be fixed if so? - but they are (support) rather than (feature-request).

Does this change influence some other well-known bugs connected to tag synonyms - such as searching and list of top users? For example: How to find a question by its old tag when that tag is synonymized with another and How does tag synonym affect top users list?

@Martin This fix only applies to the dupehammer for tag synonyms. We will review the posts and mark them appropriately.

Hm.. I just attempted to close this question, but it left a "Vote" to close

Re-added the status review tag. We will investigate.

@Bella_Blue As far as I can tell, it was only fixed for one direction - if a question is tagged with a synonym and the user holds the gold badge for the master tag. In this case, the use holds the gold badge for the synonym and still cannot close questions with the master tag. The fix needs to be implemented in both directions.

@ddavison we deployed another update to allow users with gold tag badge on a synonymized tag to close a question with the parent tag. However, please note that this fix is not retroactive so any posts that you previously cast a close vote on with the privilege will not close with a single vote. This should work as expected for future questions.

The behaviour you're seeing is the synonym system itself being broken.
For implementation reasons, all of the behaviour you've seen, and the behaviour seen by others in the comments, is caused by tag synonyms both existing and not existing at the same time.
You would think a synonym means "all of these tags are now tagged that instead", but it doesn't. internally, yes, but this isn't reflected until an edit is attempted. This means that, even though the tags are synonyms, they aren't fully the same tag. This is why search is broken, and this is why you don't currently have a tag score of 1500+ in selenium-webdriver; the score from selenium didn't transfer, so you didn't get that tag badge.
Even if it fully transferred, you risk having the inverse problem; being unable to close selenium questions with selenium-webdriver. There are ways to fix this in the system, but that requires dev time.
Historically, the solution has been to merge tags. Tag mergers involve doing what you think a synonym did, but it also does so irreversibly. This is why many tags don't get merged; if it turns out the synonym was bad later, it's easier to remove a synonym than it is to unmerge. Unmerging tags isn't possible without dev intervention.
Merging involves a database-level rewrite, which in this case would force all selenium questions to instead be tagged selenium-webdriver. I attempted to do this for selenium, but computer said no. The query (presumably) timed out with an HTTP 500 and a generic "an unknown error occurred". Because it's a database-level rewrite, there's a lot of stuff that gets rewritten. In addition to the 100599 questions (0.4% of all questions!) needing to be rewritten, there's also all the revisions associated with those questions, as well as some other things I don't remember. There's a lot of data to rewrite with that many questions, so it isn't surprising that the merger failed.

Mergers were likely introduced as a band-aid to avoid sorting out the issues with the synonym system. This must've also been back when the site was still tiny and merging didn't involve rewriting over 100000 questions and probably at least a few hundred thousand revisions.
It's therefore possible that the behaviour observed here is by design; that the intent was for mergers to be done early and often. A merger would fix all the problems presented here, and it wouldn't require any dev time (... disregarding the dev time required to perform the merge, seeing as the mod tool likely times out too fast for it to work). So to answer your question:

On Stack Overflow, I possess the selenium Gold badge, but the permissions don't seem to apply to its synonyms. Does this selenium badge also apply to its synonym selenium-webdriver? Or do I need to unlock a badge for that tag?

Under the current system, yes. You shouldn't need to, because the score should transfer, but a full transfer would mean you risk not being able to close selenium questions anymore, so we're still back to tag badges needing to respect synonyms.
Simply put, this is a consequence of tag synonyms being poorly handled in every single part of the system, and it's absolutely a bug, but so is the rest of the synonym system.

I have asked about the issue with the timeout on [meta.se]: How can be big tags merged (i.e., when the moderators' tools fail)?
